# Download pdf file using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Hello i need to download pdf file from mysql db using php. It works on localhost but when i host it on server, it won't work, said "failed to load pdf". I really don't know where i am going wrong. Can anybody suggest me.

```
<?php 
include 'connection.php';
$sql=mysqli_query($connection,"Select name,content from pdf where id = (select max(id) from pdf)"); 
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$filename=$result['name'];//  echo $filename;
$filecontent=$result['content'];
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
readfile($filecontent); 
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Code for upload is

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="box">
<tr>
<td>please select a file</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="16000000">
<input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile"> 
</td>
<td width="80"><input name="upload" type="submit" id="upload" value=" Upload "></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload'])&&$_FILES['userfile']['size']>0)
{

    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);
    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName); echo "<br>".$fileName."<br>";
    }
    if($db)
    { 
       $query = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO pdf (name, size, type, content) VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')") or die('Error, query failed');
      echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
    }
    else 
    { 
      echo "file upload failed"; 
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: So, you save the pdf content in your database? What type is this field in the database?

Comment: What is the type of this db field?

Comment: yes, saved pdf content in db field named 'content' n type is varchar(10000).

Comment: If stored in db (as opposed to the more common practice of using the file system), then a PDF would normally be stored as a BLOB

Comment: @Strawberry i made it BLOB too but still not working.

Comment: The code you posted is not for a BLOB stored pdf, maybe you should refresh it to the BLOB version so we can see if there's any problem you didn't see.

Comment: ok  @Li-chih Wu i won't go for BLOB type. What should i do, not working.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a `varchar(10000)` a lot of the data from the pdf is truncated. You have to use a `binary` field in the database, this will keep all special characters from the file content.

Comment: i do as you said. i made it binary, but still gives error. Is it necessary to give a lencth to binary field? if yes then What length should give to that field?

Comment: You do need to add a length. This depends on how big the pdf files are. Also how do you put the files in the database. Another suggestion: if possible, don't store the file in your database, store a link to the file and save the file on your webhost.

Comment: i uploaded pdf file on server using upload code. It works at localhost. I can see pdf file contents using varchar(10000) on localhost but not working when i host it on server. & i did what u said, added binary and length is 10 but still not working.

Comment: Can you show us the code from the upload form? We are not sure how you are saving your files.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
include 'connection.php';
$sql=mysqli_query($connection,"Select name,content from pdf where id = (select max(id) from pdf)"); 
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$filename=$result['name'];//  echo $filename;
$filecontent=$result['content'];
var_dump($filecontent, file_exists($filecontent));
mysqli_close($connection);
```

var_dump value of $filecontent, see if it's a file name.

If it's a file name, check if that file exists in your localhost, but not in your hosting server.

Comment: He stores his files in the database. You don't need to check whether the file exists.

Comment: He thinks he stored the pdf in db, but in his code he used "readfile($filecontent);", so I think he doesn't really know where he stored the pdf.

Comment: ah indeed, my apologies, I didn't notice that.

Comment: OK @ Li-chih Wu, but what about content field.? can i make it binary(10) or leave it as varchar(10000)

Comment: If the code runs ok in localhost, then you are using the "content" field as file name, not binary content.
If that's the case, you should keep using varchar, and try figuring out how to get the pdf file upload to your server, and matching "content" field with correct file name.